# Whats wrong with this simple var assignment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've this RecyclerView adapter class which has a method offsetRound in it.

```
class LeagueRoundAdapter(private val rounds: List<RoundVO>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchViewHolder>() {
    private var round: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            matches = rounds[value].matches

            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }


    fun offsetRound(offset: Int): Int {
        var newround = round + offset;
        if (newround !in 0 until rounds.size) {
            return round
        }
        round = newround
        return newround
    }

    private var matches = rounds[round].matches


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MatchViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_match, parent, false)
        return MatchViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return rounds[round].matches.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MatchViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val matchVO = matches[position]
        holder.bind(matchVO)
    }
}
```

When I push A prev/next button I want to increment/decrement the current round:

```
private fun setupEvents(){
    btn_next_round.setOnClickListener{
        val round = getAdapter().offsetRound(Integer.parseInt(btn_next_round.tag as String))
        txt_round_info.text = "$round"
    }

    btn_prev_round.setOnClickListener{
        val round = getAdapter().offsetRound(Integer.parseInt(btn_prev_round.tag as String))
        txt_round_info.text = "$round"
    }
}
```

the button tags are "1" and "-1".

The problem is that in this line `round = newround` the variable round doesn't take the value of newround, as you can see in this debug print:

Before assignment:

[image]

After:

[image]

I'm kind of sleepy at the moment. Am I doing something stupid that I can not figure out?

EDIT

I put a LOG before and after:

```
println("1. round: $round newround: $newround")
round = newround
println("2. round: $round newround: $newround")
println("----")
```

Pressing the button multiple times:

```
2018-12-18 23:08:11.830 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 1. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:11.830 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 2. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:11.830 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: ----
2018-12-18 23:08:11.856 3349-3354/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=504KB, data=333KB
2018-12-18 23:08:11.857 3349-3354/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=496KB, data=281KB
2018-12-18 23:08:14.910 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 1. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:14.911 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 2. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:14.911 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: ----
2018-12-18 23:08:15.661 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 1. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:15.661 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 2. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:15.661 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: ----
2018-12-18 23:08:16.422 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 1. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:16.422 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: 2. round: 0 newround: 1
2018-12-18 23:08:16.423 3349-3349/com.github.alexpfx.soccerchampionship I/System.out: ----
```

Comment: yes. I put a log before and after the assignment. Furthermore, i'm seting the value to a label in the UI. When I press the button first time it shows "1" (because I returned newround from method). But when I press multiple times it keep showing 1 (because value to round is always 0).

Comment: Do you have a custom setter for `round`? Looks like you forgot to actually [save the value in the backing `field`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have `set` defined for `round`:

```
private var round: Int = 0
    set(value) {
        matches = rounds[value].matches

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

But you forgot to actually [update the value of the backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields). Setter should look like this:

```
private var round: Int = 0
    set(value) {
        field = value // Note this line
        matches = rounds[value].matches

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: that was the problem!